# combine node.js api-layers with git - how to structure?

Tags: node.js, git

I don't even know how to put my question into words. So i'll try describing it this way. I have 3 node.js-code-bases, each a git repository on its own:

```
api
api-base
api-base-specific
```

"api" delivers some sort of framework, which "api-base" extends from, which then "api-base-specific" extends from. Whereas only the final one is what will ever be in production. Though, each single one should be "node app.js"-able oder "npm test"-able, when git-cloning it on its own.

When working on "api-base-specific", the directory structure would look like this:

```
.
  app.js
  /lib
    /api        <- git submodule "api"
      api.js
      ....
    /api-base   <- git submodule "api-base"
      api.js
      ...
    /api-base-specific
      api.js
      ...
  /tests
```

This works well. However, when i "check out" "api-base" on its own, there is no "lib" directory having a "api-base" directory. Get what i mean?

I'd like to build up the "api" and "api-specific" repositories in the same manner as "api-base-specific". And then kind of submodule them in "api-base-specific"/lib, but step in at their "lib/api-base"-directory-level.

Hope you get my "question". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split all of them into separate modules and get a file structure like this:

```
.
  app.js
  /node_modules
    /api
      api.js
      /node_modules
        /api-base   <- git submodule "api-base"
          api.js
          /node_modules
            /api-base-specific
              api.js
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me at modules. then require("api-base") will look for "/node_modules/api-base/(index.js|index.node|package.json)": http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders